# Passport and Canadian visitor visa expiring inDecember 2019

Tags: passports

Hi Team my Indian passport and Canadian Visa are expiring in December 2019 Could I visit Canada in August 2019 and come back in October 2019?

Comment: Thanks David and Doggen So I could travel ? And there won’t be any isssues at the immigration right?

Comment: We can't guarantee that you won't encounter problems at immigration, but if you do, they won't be related to your passport validity or visa validity.